# call the first data in the array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
 Array
    (
       [0] => Array
           (
               [kasus] => P001
               [euclidean] => 1.4142135623731
               [similarity] => 0.97058823529412
               [penyakit] => Polio
           )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [kasus] => P002
            [euclidean] => 1.7320508075689
            [similarity] => 0.9656862745098
            [penyakit] => Polio
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [kasus] => P003
            [euclidean] => 3.4641016151378
            [similarity] => 0.81372549019608
            [penyakit] => Demam Berdarah Dengue
        )
)
```

from aray above i just want to retrieve the data of the first penyakit sub array in aray. how to retrieve data using php code?

Comment: You want all the first sub array or one of the values in the first sub array?

Comment: If you struggle with arrays PHP is not going to be any fun at all.

Comment: I'm sorry I just learned

Comment: `$array[0]['penyakit']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If element in your array might have not the key 'penyakit', 
perhaps, this is what you want.

```
$penyakitList = array_column($data, 'penyakit'); // replace $data with your array
if(!empty($penyakitList)) {
    return $penyakitList[0];
}else {
    // return what you'd like to set
}
```